# It is possible in mysql query to dynamically sum row based on column with criteria?

Tags: mysql, database

So, its my original table. The duration is in second.

| Duration | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 0 |
| 30 | 0 |
| 31 | 1 |
| 30 | 1 |
| 31 | 1 |
| 31 | 0 |
| 31 | 1 |
| 30 | 0 |
| 30 | 0 |
| 30 | 0 |
| 31 | 0 |
| 30 | 1 |
| 30 | 1 |
| 30 | 0 |

and i want the result is something like this (if possible)

| Status | sum of duration |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 60 |
| 1 | 92 |
| 0 | 31 |
| 1 | 31 |
| 0 | 121 |
| 1 | 60 |
| 0 | 30 |

i want to sum the duration for each status (0 and 1), i have try some query like *sum*, *group*, or *where* modification... but i dont get the correct one.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance : )

**note :**
**+ i use mysql phpmyadmin**
**++ im sorry, i just edited the result that i desire. because there is slight mistake in my manual count**

Comment: `sum(duration) over (partition by status order by duration)`  not sure what you are ordering by but change it to whatever you are.

Comment: We need your current SQL so that we can help you

Comment: What is used to control the order of your first result? It will be near impossible to achieve the wanted result without controls to match the order of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that an RDBMS table is a **set**.

What you're showing in your question looks like
an ordered list, rather than a set.

Write some code that reads
`duration`, `status`, and writes
`duration`, `status`, `session_id`.

Now, with those seven distinct IDs appearing in a table,
you're in a good position to use `SUM(duration)`
in a `GROUP BY session_id` query.